# correctly convert 'month-day' format to 'month-day-year' format using dateutil

Tags: python, python-dateutil

I use `dateutil.parser.parse` function to convert something like `01.01` or `12.31` to datetime where year is a current year. So `01.01` becomes `01.01.2019`. This code however does not work:

```
from dateutil import parser.parse
date = '05.05'
print(parser.parse(date))
```

Result:

```
>>>  datetime.datetime(2019, 3, 5, 0, 0)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You should put `-` or nothing between them:

```
In [3]: from dateutil.parser import parse
   ...: date = '05-05' # also works with '05 05'
   ...: print(parse(date))
2019-05-05 00:00:00
```

Comment: what if a user accidently put '.' there? I mean I can replace everything but digits to '-' before proceeding to parsing, of course, just wanted to know if there is a built-in solution

Comment: @PhilippChapkovski you cannot blame `dateutil` for user mistakes. `05.05` is very ambiguous to be parsed correctly.